# Not able to create and then save the data into mongo db using express framework(worked now.)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

following are my code , It is running well if , I find from database but its only saving IDs into database on create method

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();


// create application/json parser
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/quicks');
const db = mongoose.connection;

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);


app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.post('/createuser', (req, res) => {
    let value = {
        name : req.body.Name,
        email : req.body.Email,
        password : req.body.Password
    };
    User.create(value)
    .then((records) => {return res.json(records)})
    .catch((err) => {return res.json("err")})
})


app.post('/user', (req, res) => {
    let value = {
        _id : req.body.ID
    };
    user.findOne(value)
    .then((records) => {return res.json(records)})
    .catch((err) => {return res.json("err")})
})


app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!'))
```

i am not able to get the data which i have created . Only the ID is created. what would be the possible error?

Answer (score 1):

In your schema email and password fields are missing.

try this,

```
app.post('/createuser', (req, res) => {
    let value = {
        name: req.body.Name,
        email: req.body.Email,
        password: req.body.Password
    };
    let model = new User();
    model = Object.assign(model, value);
    model.save()
        .then((records) => {
            return res.json(records)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            return res.json("err")
        })
})
```

Comment: Its working with this, Thank You! But I have been doing this to all of my previous code . which worked well with if I required model/schema from other file. Can you please tell me . what was wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not sure how to create works, I always use save function.

Comment: Thank YOU ! Anyways . Its my fault . That code was also working but I was putting name in postman instead of Name. Anyways . Closing this thread